# Word meaning "close in time, or presently happening"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, time

Is there a word that can be used to describe something that is either close in time, or currently happening?

Something like "proximate" or "imminent", but without the implication that the thing has not happened/started happening yet.

Comment: Is there a problem with _current_? Or _present_.

Comment: Do you want a word which means "Currently happening, but if it isn't then it's just about to start happening"?

Comment: @AndrewLeach, yep, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: It depends whether you want "close to now" or "close to something else".  Concomitant is correct for "at the same time as some other event."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Current***

> : presently elapsing  (2) : occurring in or
>   existing at the present time  (3) : most recent
>
> : generally accepted, used, practiced, or prevalent at the moment

Answer (score 5):

[*Contemporary*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contemporary):

> From the same time period, coexistent in time.

Answer (score 2):

You nearly got 'em all already.

Without reference to the present, it would be: ***temporal-proximity***.

With the context 'present,' it could be ***current***.

And why not the elegant ***now***? That can mean just what you want, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

*[Ongoing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ongoing)*

> : Continuing, permanent
>
> : Presently or currently happening; being in progress

Comment: This seems to specific to also include things that have not yet begun.

Answer (score 0):

Concomitant:

1. adjective-- naturally accompanying or associated.
2. noun-- a phenomenon that naturally accompanies or follows something.